# IntelliJ Project Files Changed

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

My friend and I are working as a team on a project through Dropbox. Previously I have used Eclipse and Eclipse would automatically update the files in view. Unfortunately every time we make a new change IntelliJ says this:

[image]

We then have to press *Yes* which then closes all of our tabs and is very annoying. Is there a way to disable this in IntelliJ? (We want it to work functionally equivalent to Eclipse if possible!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is caused not by changes in actual code files, but IDEA's configuration files, those that are in the `.idea/` folder inside your project.

One way to resolve this would be to use [Selective Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/175) to stop syncing configuration folder.

Comment: Your answer seems most likely to solve Jire's immediate need, though I still think Dropbox is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shortcut below to synchronize the classes.

> ctrl + alt + y

And also check your intellij settings by navigating through `HotSwap` in `File > Settings`  and then select `Reload classes in background` also you can use the shortcut as below to refresh.

> ctrl + F5

Comment: It seems like this option is the default in IntelliJ 14. Having _HotSwap_ enabled unfortunately does not get rid of the popup.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to stop using dropbox.  Using git is a much better solution for collaboration, and there are free git services. There are even some that allow free private repos for smaller teams.  IDE project files should generally *not* be part of your source code.

Also, there are additional benefits to using proper source code controls, such auditing and history, merging, and so much more.

Comment: We have both used Git before however I didn't find it as easy to use as something like Dropbox. Is there some guide as to how to use easily use Git in IntelliJ?

Comment: I can't agree with this. While Dropbox can't be a proper version control system, it does provide an easy way to backup source codes and share with other teammates / collaborator **instantly**. If you're working on extreme programming style, you really can't wait the Commit & Update process; it's just way too slow.

Comment: Commit/Update takes a few seconds, and it is probably safer than Dropbox.  I'll admit I don't have much experience with Dropbox, but does it handle conflicts at all?  When two people are editing the same source file at the same time?

Comment: @Jire, IntelliJ has integration with git under there VCS menus.  There are also a few tutorials out there.   It is important to note that with git there are some differences in workflows and methodologies that may take some time to get used to, but ultimately it aids in better software design, development, and releases.

Comment: @Daniel Unfortunately I find the Git process far too slow for the type of work my friend and I are doing. We want something even faster than Dropbox, as there is Saros for Eclipse!

Comment: My opinion is that if you need that level of "real-time" collaboration, your software design isn't decoupled enough.   There is a place for pair-programming, but that's quite different than shared filesystem.  I'll admit ignorance of your particular project.